# The type argument '{ id: number;ectc..}' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User[]

Tags: angular, typescript, web, frontend, interceptor

I'm creating a fake backend for my login using interceptors. I have this error and I am unable to get over it. Sto creando un piccolo e-commerce e devo utilizzare gli interceptor per ritornare un token dell'utente. Sto utilizzando Angular e typescript

fake-backend.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpRequest, HttpResponse, HttpHandler, HttpEvent, HttpInterceptor, HTTP_INTERCEPTORS } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable, of, throwError } from 'rxjs';
import { delay, mergeMap, materialize, dematerialize } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { User } from 'app/shared/model/user-model';


const users: User [] = [{ id: 1, name: 'test', lastname: 'test', email: 'Test', username: 'User',password: 'test', token: 'Test'  }];

@Injectable()
export class FakeBackendInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const { url, method, headers, body } = request;

        // wrap in delayed observable to simulate server api call
        return of(null)
            .pipe(mergeMap(handleRoute))
            .pipe(materialize()) // call materialize and dematerialize to ensure delay even if an error is thrown (https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/issues/648)
            .pipe(delay(500))
            .pipe(dematerialize());

        function handleRoute() {
            switch (true) {
                case url.endsWith('/users/authenticate') && method === 'POST':
                    return authenticate();
                case url.endsWith('/users') && method === 'GET':
                    return getUsers();
                default:
                    // pass through any requests not handled above
                    return next.handle(request);
            }    
        }

        // route functions

        function authenticate() {
            const { username, password } = body;
            const user = users.find(x => x.username === username && x.password === password);
            if (!user) return error('Username or password is incorrect');
            return ok({
                id: user.id,
                name: user.name,
                lastname: user.lastname,
                email: user.email,
                token: 'fake-jwt-token'
            })
        }

;
```

user-model.ts

```
export interface User {
    id: number;
    name: string;
    lastname: string;
    email: string;
    username: string;
    password: string;
    token?: string;
}
```

Più precisamente ho questo errore:
"

```
The type argument '{ id: number; name: string; lastname: string; email:string; tokens: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'User[]'.
  Object literal can only specify known properties and 'id' does not exist in type 'User[]'.ts(2345)
```

"

Comment: Mark the line on which the typescript is complaining. In general, it says: `you are assigning a single user to variable of type array of users`

Comment: i.e. `return ok({...})` likely should be `return ok([{...}])`

Comment: [Please make sure you are writing in English](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/13684/511366). Sembra che tu non abbia tradotto tutto il testo italiano in inglese.

Comment: Please consider [edit]ing your code to be a self-contained [mre] suitable for pasting into a standalone IDE.  Dependencies on third-party libraries should be removed unless they are important for your question.  Dependencies on private code that we can't see should be removed entirely. Good luck!